# Error using complex vector

Tags: c++, vector, complex-numbers

I need to access a specific element of a vector of complex data in C++.

Here is what I have:

```
vector< complex<float> > x; // Create vector of complex numbers
x.push_back(complex<float>(1, 2)); // Place 1 + j2 in vector
x.push_back(complex<float>(2, 1)); // Place 2 + j1 in vector

// Attempt at accessing the zero-th elements real part
float temp1 = x.at(0).real;
float temp2 = x[0].real;
```

This gives the following error in Visual Studio 2015:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C3867   'std::_Complex_base::real': non - standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    opencv_dft  c : \users\josh\VS_project\main.cpp 101

Comment: Use `x[0].real()` or even better `using std::real; ... real(x[0])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses in the calls to `real()`. You need:

```
float temp1 = x.at(0).real();
float temp2 = x[0].real();
```

`real()` is a member function, not a data member.

Answer (score 0):

No need for casting in statement x.push_back(complex(float){1, 2})-though doesn't hurt to cast.  Also don't forget using namespace std for statements using vector and complex.

Also don't forget ()s in x.at(0).real so it is x.at(0).real();.

Here is how I wrote a program using vectors and complex numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    void main() {
        complex<float> a = { 1,2 };
        a = { 1,4 };
        vector<complex<float>> av;
        av.push_back({ 1,2 });
        cout << av.at(0).real();
    }
```

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you very much.